# Show element depending on select value

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a question about how to get a var and then show his specific div.
In the exemple, if I select C then Juice, menu 1 need to appear. 
The problem is, I have no idea how to get the var and then simply make the dive appear.
When I select an other ingredient, like A then Tea, menu-1 need to hidde and menu-2 must appear.

Thanks for your help.

```js
var mealsByCategory = {
  A: ["Soup", "Juice", "Tea", "Others"],
  B: ["Soup", "Juice", "Water", "Others"],
  C: ["Soup", "Juice", "Coffee", "Tea", "Others"]
}

function changecat(value) {
  if (value.length == 0) document.getElementById("category").innerHTML = "<option></option>";
  else {
    var catOptions = "";
    for (categoryId in mealsByCategory[value]) {
      catOptions += "<option>" + mealsByCategory[value][categoryId] + "</option>";
    }
    document.getElementById("category").innerHTML = catOptions;
  }
}

var Juice = this.id;
$('menu-1' + id).css({
  "display": "inline-block"
});
```

```css
.menu-1 {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select name="meal" id="meal" onChange="changecat(this.value);">
  <option value="" disabled selected>Select</option>
  <option value="A">A</option>
  <option value="B">B</option>
  <option value="C">C</option>
</select>
<select name="category" id="category">
  <option value="" disabled selected>Select</option>
</select>
<div class="menu-1">menu 1</div>
```

[JS Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/tom_pouce_dev/0em2x8cf/16/)

Comment: I don't understand how much menus you want, and how you pick which one you want to show. Can you please clarify that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is one way of achieving it.

Note that I have added only one rule (one that you have specified in your question) so the only functionality of this code (apart from populationg second `select` with new options) is that when you select `A` and then `Tea`, `menu1` hides and `menu2` appears.

If you want another rules (which you probably do), then you can specify them the same way I did with `if (selectEl1.value === 'A' && selectEl2.value === 'Tea')`.

```js
var mealsByCategory = {
  A: ["Soup", "Juice", "Tea", "Others"],
  B: ["Soup", "Juice", "Water", "Others"],
  C: ["Soup", "Juice", "Coffee", "Tea", "Others"]
}

const menuEl = document.querySelector('.menu');
const selectEl1 = document.querySelector('#meal');
const selectEl2 = document.querySelector('#category')

selectEl1.addEventListener('change', event => {
  const meals = mealsByCategory[selectEl1.value]

  // clear the content of the second select and populate it with new options
  selectEl2.innerHTML = '';
  meals.forEach(item => {
    const option = document.createElement('option');
    selectEl2.appendChild(option);
    option.textContent = item;
  });
});

selectEl2.addEventListener('change', event => {
  if (selectEl1.value === 'A' && selectEl2.value === 'Tea') {
    document.querySelector('.menu1').style.display = 'none';
    document.querySelector('.menu2').style.display = 'block';
  }
});
```

```css
.menu2 {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<select name="meal" id="meal">
  <option value="" disabled selected>Select</option>
  <option value="A">A</option>
  <option value="B">B</option>
  <option value="C">C</option>
</select>
<select name="category" id="category">
  <option value="" disabled selected>Select</option>
</select>
<div class="menu1">Menu 1</div>
<div class="menu2">Menu 2</div>
```

**UPDATE** (based on provided [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/tom_pouce_dev/vzayctov/))

```js
const CityByCategory = {
    A: ["NY-District-1", "NY-District-2", "NY-District-3"],
    B: ["LA-District-1", "LA-District-2", "LA-District-3"],
    C: ["SF-District-1", "SF-District-2", "SF-District-3"]
}

const clearContent = () => {
  const allDistricts = document.querySelectorAll('.district');
  allDistricts.forEach(item => {
    item.style.display = 'none';
  });
}

const citySelect = document.querySelector('#city');
const categorySelect = document.querySelector('#category')

citySelect.addEventListener('change', event => {
  clearContent();
  const districts = CityByCategory[citySelect.value];
  document.querySelector('.' + districts[0]).style.display = 'block';

  categorySelect.innerHTML = '';
  districts.forEach(item => {
    const option = document.createElement('option');
    categorySelect.appendChild(option);
    option.textContent = item;
  });
});

categorySelect.addEventListener('change', event => {
  clearContent();
  const selected = categorySelect.value;
  const district = document.querySelector('.' + selected);

  if (district) { district.style.display = 'block'; }
});
```

```css
[class*="NY"] {
    display:none;
}
[class*="SF"] {
    display:none;
}
[class*="LA"] {
    display:none;
}
```

```html
<select name="city" id="city">
  <option value="" disabled selected>Select</option>
  <option value="A">NY</option>
  <option value="B">LA</option>
  <option value="C">SF</option>
</select>
<select name="category" id="category">
  <option value="" disabled selected>Select</option>
</select>
<div class="NY-District-1 district">NY-District-1-Adress-1</div>
<div class="NY-District-2 district">NY-District-1-Adress-2</div>
<div class="LA-District-1 district">LA-District-1-Adress-1</div>
<div class="LA-District-2 district">LA-District-1-Adress-2</div>
<div class="SF-District-1 district">SF-District-1-Adress-1</div>
<div class="SF-District-2 district">SF-District-1-Adress-2</div>
```

Comment: Sorry if it wasn't clear. I improve my example here : https://jsfiddle.net/tom_pouce_dev/vzayctov/

First you select a city then a district and then the info of the district appears. 
I can select the district no problem. The only things is that I can't find a way to show the district elements.

Comment: @Thom-pouce-dev Well, you say that info appears but I don't see any info appearing. And what do you mean by show the district elements? Show where, in console or some element? And what are district elements, do you mean properties of the chosen district?

Comment: The district elements appears in the HTML. I have for example : <div class="NY-District-1-Adress-1 district">NY-District-1-Adress-1</div>
I select NY, then Manhattan and then there is random informations.
But when I choose for example Manhattan in the second step, I can't make the adresse appear.

Comment: Here is my updated version : https://jsfiddle.net/tom_pouce_dev/vzayctov/7/

Comment: @Thom-pouce-dev No, I've meant you to see my updated answer :) It should already work as you expect.

Comment: Oh yeah right. Thanks so much :) Sorry to ask this but do you know why it doesnt work on JS fiddle with the same code ? https://jsfiddle.net/tom_pouce_dev/vzayctov/11/
Anyway thank you so much

Comment: @Thom-pouce-dev I think that it has something to do with how the fiddle loads JS code (it might load it sooner than it loads the html so the event listeners would not bind to the html elements), but that is just guess.

Answer (score 1):

you can use `.find()` and `:selected`  like this:

```
var selected_value = $('#my-select').find('option:selected');

if (selected_value === 'C') {
    $('#target').removeClass('hidden')
}
```

refs:

https://api.jquery.com/find/

https://api.jquery.com/selected-selector/

note: this isn't going to work via copy-and-paste you will have to amend for your script. This is just the core principle :)

Answer (score 1):

It is unclear for me what you asked, but anyway…
Here is a snippet where I tried to optimize your code and I propose something that could be what you wanted:

```js
var mealsByCategory = {
  A: ["Soup", "Juice", "Tea", "Others"],
  B: ["Soup", "Juice", "Water", "Others"],
  C: ["Soup", "Juice", "Coffee", "Tea", "Others"]
}

// Code on change of 1st select
$('#meal').on('change', function() {

  // Get the selected value of the 1st select
  var value = $(this).val();
  
  // Populate options of 2nd select
  var catOptions = "<option value='' disabled selected>Select</option>";
  for (categoryId in mealsByCategory[value]) {
    catOptions += "<option>" + mealsByCategory[value][categoryId] + "</option>";
  }
  $("#category").html(catOptions);
  
});

// Code on change of 2nd select (proposition, don't get what you really want)
$('#category').on('change', function() {
  var index = $("#category option:selected").index();
  $('.menus').hide();
  $('.menu-' + index).show();
});
```

```css
.menus {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select name="meal" id="meal">
  <option value="" disabled selected>Select</option>
  <option value="A">A</option>
  <option value="B">B</option>
  <option value="C">C</option>
</select>
<select name="category" id="category">
  <option value="" disabled selected>Select</option>
</select>
<div class="menus menu-1">menu 1</div>
<div class="menus menu-2">menu 2</div>
<div class="menus menu-3">menu 3</div>
<div class="menus menu-4">menu 4</div>
<div class="menus menu-5">menu 5</div>
```

Feel free to comment for any modification or to explain me the way you want it!

Hope it helps.